# How to use file glob in a different directory in CMake

Tags: cmake

`file(GLOB ...)` and `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` only seems to work on the current source directory. Is there any way to glob a different directory?

Comment: That doesn't rind a bell. Can you please give a [mcve]?

Answer (score 10):

[`file(GLOB)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/file.html) can be a little confusing at first, i had a similar issue a few months ago.

You have to specify your path directly in the `<globbing-expressions>` :

```
file(GLOB <variable>
     [LIST_DIRECTORIES true|false] [RELATIVE <path>]
     [<globbing-expressions>...])
```

For example :

```
file(GLOB my_cpp_list "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/directory/*.cpp")
foreach(file_path ${my_cpp_list})
    message(${file_path})
endforeach()
```

Will print the path of all *.cpp* files in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/directory`.

Comment: Did you test this with a directory that is not a subdirectory of `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`?

Comment: Yes and it works fine : `file(GLOB my_cpp_list "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../test/*.cpp")`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where no matter what path I specified, I would get a glob from CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR. The issue was that the path I was providing to GLOB wasn't valid, and it was reverting (gracefully, but annoyingly) to CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR. For example, either of the following will create the symptom you see:

```
file(GLOB my_cpp_list "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/directory *.cpp")
```

I forgot the "/" after "directory".  This was why I never got valid results, even with valid directory names.

```
file(GLOB my_cpp_list "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/directoryy/*.cpp")
```

There is no sub-folder named "directoryy"